# My browser doesn't think my Javascript is ... Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

HTML:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/grabber.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#search-js').submit(function() {
                var username = $("#bar-js").val();
                var result = grab(username);
                alert(result);
                $(".contents").html(result["twitter"]);
            });
        });
</script>
```

js/grabber.js:

```
function grab(username) {
    //var results = {};

    // run all the things
    //results["twitter"] = check_twitter(username);

    // return your (huge) map
    //return results;
    return "stuff";
}
```

When I trigger the function, nothing happens. If I take the code inside `grabber.js` and embed it into the page, it works. When I view the source with Chrome and click on the `js/grabber.js` link (in the HTML), Chrome tries to download the file instead of display it. If I click on Google's jQuery link, it gets displayed.

I'm new to the javascript world, but I've been at this for a while and can't seem to figure it out.

**EDIT:**

Chrome developer tools is giving me this:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/x-js: "http://0.0.0.0:8000/js/grabber.js".
```

I'm using Python's SimpleHTTPServer to create a temporary server for quick development. Could that be the issue?

Comment: If you have Firebug, please use console.log() instead of alert()

Comment: I came across Firebug when trying to debug this, however it seems that the extension for Chrome is "Lite" and doesn't have javascript support.

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler or Charles to look at the http requests. Is the content type correct?

Comment: @MaxMackie chrome has its own debugger, hit `f12` at the chrome and it will show up

Comment: ... uhmmm... that sounds like issue with your server.

Comment: Does the Chrome inspector say anything about misinterpreting grabber.js MIME type? Check that, please. Also, try with a different .js file from your server. Since you're loading jQuery from CDN, this could be a server related problem.

Comment: I added a chrome console message

Comment: You don't really need those "type" attribute on your `<script>` tags.

Comment: @Pointy removing them didn't change anything

Comment: Yes I suspect the problem to be with your server. As others have said, the best thing to do would be to check the HTTP headers. Another tool that might help would be the [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) add-on for Firefox. That lets you track all HTTP requests, and shows all request and response headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for some reason your server is not setting the correct mime-type for .js files, try adding this to your .htaccess:

```
AddType text/javascript .js
```

Or maybe:

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
```

Comment: What I find strange is that Chrome tries to download the js file, as if not recognizing its format. That's why I thought it would be a server problem.

Comment: "I'm using Python's SimpleHTTPServer" - no htaccess available.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, to be fair he posted the answer before I updated my question

Comment: True, I don't know hot SimpleHTTPServer does this